# toFixed() is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am having difficulty with the toFixed() function. In the code below I am trying to fix a calculation to two decimals when I call setState, but for some reason I get an error that say `toFixed() is not a function`

I made sure that both tipPercent and subtotal are considered numbers with `typeof()`

```
this.setState({
    subtotal,
    tip: (this.state.tipPercent * subtotal).toFixed(2),
    tax: (0.07 * subtotal).toFixed(2),
    fee: 1,
  });
```

Here is the total block of code:

```
calculateTotal = () => {
   var total = 0;
   var subtotal = 0;

   // calculate subtotal
   Object.keys(this.state.bill.items).map((item) => {
     subtotal +=
       this.state.bill.items[item].price *
       this.state.bill.items[item].quantity;
   });

   // calculate tax/tip
   if (subtotal !== 0) {
     this.setState({
       subtotal,
       tip: (this.state.tipPercent * subtotal).toFixed(2),
       tax: (0.07 * subtotal).toFixed(2),
       fee: 1,
     });
   } else {
     this.setState({
       subtotal,
       tip: 0,
       tax: 0,
     });
   }

   total = subtotal + this.state.tax + this.state.tip + this.state.fee;

   this.setState({ total: total, loading: false });
};
```

Where `this.state.bill.items` would look something like this:

```
Array [
   Object {
      "item": "Sip of Sunshine",
      "price": 6.5,
      "quantity": 4,
   },
   Object {
     "item": "Sip of Sunshine",
     "price": 6.5,
     "quantity": 3,
   },
   Object {
     "item": "Bud Light",
     "price": 2.75,
     "quantity": 2,
   },
 ]
```

Comment: What value holds `subtotal`? Which line fails, `tip` or `tax`?

Comment: try like this `(parseFloat(this.state.tipPercent) * parseFloat( subtotal)).toFixed(2)` ..

Comment: Multiplication *always* returns a number. At most, it will return `NaN` if at least one of the operands is `undefined` or `NaN`. Therefore, I don't see how this code can throw the error you say - `(NaN).toFixed(2)` will produce the string `"NaN"` not an error. We need a [mcve].

Comment: NaN also returns "number" - try `typeof NaN`

Comment: Ignore @noor's advice. If they are in fact strings of a number, they'd be converted to number automatically. The fact that you're getting that error means `subtotal` isn't a number or a stringified number. If anything, try `(console.log(subtotal, typeof subtotal) || 0.07 * subtotal).toFixed(2)` to get a print of what that line is doing.

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.bill.items).map((item)` - please don't use `.map` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach` or a normal loop for that.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the error](https://jsbin.com/zopalibapi/1/edit?js,console). Even if I change the items used for the calculation to things that cannot convert to a number, I still get `"NaN"` at most. I suspect the error comes from elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix this solution by using the `Math.round()` operation and multiplying the whole equation by 100, then dividing by 100 which keeps the math rounded to two decimal places, as JavaScript by nature will go out many places.

Since `toFixed()` returns a string I couldn't set the state below to a proper number value. `Math.round()` fixes this by always keeping it a number rounded to two decimal places.

Here is an updated version of the `calculateTotal()` function:

```
calculateTotal = () => {
    var subtotal = 0;

    // calculate subtotal
    Object.keys(this.state.bill.items).forEach((item) => {
      subtotal +=
       this.state.bill.items[item].price *
       this.state.bill.items[item].quantity;
    });

    if (subtotal !== 0) {
      this.setState({
        subtotal,
        tip: Math.round(this.state.tipPercent * subtotal * 100) / 100,
        tax: Math.round(0.07 * subtotal * 100) / 100,
        fee: 1,
      });

      this.setState({
        total: subtotal + this.state.tax + this.state.tip + this.state.fee,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
};
```